# Data access with abstract source [java] - for dummies

Tags: java, database, interface, architecture

so this is probably a really simple question once understood.

But in simple words what is a good architecture / interface design to:

-Funnel all the data and buisness logic through a few objects (e.g. Person, Car, User ...)

-Easy swap the underlaying source of said data (MySQL DB, REST API ....)

What is the best approach for a universal top layer interface to achive this ?

Greetings,

a cat :3

Answer (score 0):

There are many architectural patterns that accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.  The most simple of these is the [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).  You should probably explore larger abstraction patterns like Layered Architecture, Onion Architecture, and the like.